# Verified downcasting if RTTI is active

Tags: c++, template, c++20, casting, rtti

In an application that uses heavily polymorphic classes, I have often the need to *downcast* a pointer or a reference to the correct derived class. They should always be of the correct derived class, but for verification / unit testing, it would be great if this could be automatically found.
Therefore, I wrote a very short **`down_cast<targettype>(sourcetype)`** template.

The idea is that

- the code uses `down_cast<>()`, to be used and looking like `static_cast<>()` or `dynamic_cast<>()`
- I can switch on RTTI for the Debug build, and it will use `dynamic_cast`, plus verify if the object are of the expected types
- I can switch off RTTI for the Release build, and it will use `static_cast` (without verification or overhead)

[This is my first venture into templates, so it might look elementary to you, sorry.]

The template:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename S>
inline T down_cast(S&& s)
{
#ifdef _CPPRTTI
  T p = dynamic_cast<T>(s);
  if constexpr (std::is_pointer<T>::value)
    assert(p != nullptr);
  return p;
#else
  return static_cast<T>(s);
#endif
}
```

and here an example that uses it:

```
class A
{
  virtual void foo() {};
};

class B : public A
{};

class C : public A  // a C is NOT a B!
{};

int main()
{
  A* a = new B;

  B* b = down_cast<B*>(a);    // ok
  B& br = down_cast<B&>(*a);  // ok

  C* c = down_cast<C*>(a);    // not ok, fails with RTTI but 'works' without RTTI
  C& cr = down_cast<C&>(*a);  // not ok, fails with RTTI but 'works' without RTTI
}
```

It works as I want it to; the last two lines are bad, and will be found with this approach; the others run fine.

**Questions: Does this make any sense; is it done right; what could I do better?**

Edit: I am aware that _CPPRTTI is Visual Studio specific; also, I could simply make a macro to replace `down_cast` but that would not be able to test the pointer, and I don't want to use macros.

Comment: Also, I can't see how your two `B` lines are substantively different from your two `C` lines. They look **exactly** equivalent, to me. Did you mean, instead, to attempt a cast from a `B` to a `C`, rather than from an `A` to a `C`?

Comment: @AdrianMole, the `A* a` is really a `B*`, not an A; check the first line in main where it is created. Downcasting this polymorphic `A*` to a `B*` is therefore _valid_, but downcasting it to a `C*` is _not_ valid.

Comment: @Agnanju Aha - OK. But now, when I test the code, it succeeds whichever part of the `#if .. #else ...` is used. (MSVC, VS 2022).

Comment: Never mind - I'm just being dim.

Answer (score 2):

Add some class hierarchy compile-time guard:

```
template <typename T, typename S>
inline T down_cast(S&& s)
{
    using base_S = std::remove_pointer_t<std::remove_cvref_t<S>>;
    using base_T = std::remove_pointer_t<std::remove_cvref_t<T>>;
    static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<base_S, base_T>);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Looks like this is a whole level better than what I built - it is compile-time, so it doesn't need RTTI at all, and works always. Thanks!!

Comment: @Aganju No, it still needs RTTI, for your case (```A* a = new B;```) there is no way to guard ```bad_cast``` from ```B&``` to ```C&``` other than ```dynamic_cast```